# Websphere AdminTask.renameNode

Tags: websphere, cluster-computing

After changing a node name using this cmd

`AdminTask.renameNode('[-nodeName localhostNode01 -newNodeName  nodeVirtual]')`

I am no longer able to start dmgr, it complains about a missing file localhostNode01/server.xml.

I looks obvious that when it changed the nodeName it missed to update dmgr config, my question is how to fix that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I tried renaming the dirs, I was able to start the manager but it was messed, therefore I opted to restore a backup I have.

I still need help about the correct procedure to renameNode.

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever synchronize the WAS configuration across all nodes, after doing this change and *before* shutting down the deployment manager?

Comment: Are you trying renaming the deployment manager node, or the federated node?

Comment: For deployment manager (you might forget to change the setupCmdLine script) - http://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/wsbroker/redirect?version=matt&product=was-nd-mp&topic=tagt_rename_dnodes
For federated you should use renameNode script - http://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/wsbroker/redirect?version=matt&product=was-nd-mp&topic=rxml_renamenode